# Difference between printf and return here is confusing?

Tags: c, return, printf

Learning K&R C, this got me confused.

Here, when I put `return k` inside the loop, it doesn't print out `k`. But when I write `printf("k :%d", k)`, it prints one value of `k`(initial condition) and exits, but does not `return` the value of `k`.

This confuses me with what exactly `return` does, it can `printf` the value of `k` as zero if it got into the loop, so why not `return k` and why exit the loop ?

```
int k;
for (k=0; k<5; ++k)
{
  printf("k :%d\n",k);
  return k;
}
```

Output:

k :0

It got into the loop so it must be true. Why not `return` the value of `k` then?

Here is the complete program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
int k;


for (k=0; k<5; ++k)
{
  printf("k %d\n",k);

  return k;
}

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: K&R C is not a good way to introduce yourself to programming. 25 years ago it might have been, but now is not then.

Comment: It doesn't return the value of k to where? Could you show us the complete program?

Comment: You need to keep reading K&R to figure out what return does.

Comment: [This resource will help you.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_statement)

Comment: `return k` will take the value of `k` as the return value of the current function, in this case, `main`. It has nothing to do with what `printf` prints.

Comment: @YuHao Why will it print nothing, why not output zero then, because that is the value of k

Answer (score 1):

It does "output" zero as the exit status code sent to the shell.

`EXIT_SUCCESS` is just a synonym for 0. `return k` and `return EXIT_SUCCESS` are doing the same thing.

To see output, you need to run a subroutine with observable effects, such as `printf`.

`return` is a flow control statement, not a subroutine. It exits the current function and "returns" control of the computer back to the calling function. In this case, that precipitates termination of the program.